# Select adr Attribute - Selenium WebDriver - Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to

Here are 2 rows of the tables HTML:

```
    <tr type="row" adr="3" tag="" id="x:442163216.17:adr:3:tag:" class="ig_ListAlt igg_ListAlt IG_Fields_Row "> 
    <td wlkd="1" type="cell" idx="0" adr="0" class="ig9a63765d ">1</td>
    <td class="ig9a63765e ">0</td>
    <td class="ig9a63765f ">true</td>
    <td class="ig9a637660 ">true</td>
    <td class="ig9a637661 ">false</td>
    <td class="ig9a637662 ">true</td>
    <td class="ig9a637663 "></td>
    <td class="ig9a637664 ">true</td>
    <td type="cell" adr="8" idx="8" class="IG_Fields_Cell IG_Cell_Selectable IG_Cell_Center ">
        <img id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Main_Main_Main_grdFields_it8_3_imgCheckVisible" src="Images/GreenCheckmarkIcon16x16.png" style="visibility:visible;">
    </td>
    <td class="ig9a637665 ">false</td>
    <td type="cell" adr="10" idx="10" class="IG_Fields_Cell IG_Cell_Selectable IG_Cell_Center ">
        <img id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Main_Main_Main_grdFields_it10_3_imgCheckRequired" src="Images/GreenCheckmarkIcon16x16.png" style="visibility:hidden;">
    </td>
    <td class="ig9a637666 ">Loan Type</td>
    <td tabindex="-1" wlkd="1" type="cell" adr="12" idx="12" class="IG_Field_Field_Name ">Loan Type</td>
    <td type="cell" adr="13" idx="13" class="IG_Fields_Cell ">Loan Type</td>
    <td type="cell" adr="14" idx="14" class="IG_Fields_Cell "></td>
    <td type="cell" adr="15" idx="15" class="IG_Fields_Cell IG_Cell_Center ">
        <a href="javascript:ShowCheckboxGroupPopup();"><img src="/images/Configure-Icon-16x15.png" alt="" class="Configure"></a>
    </td>
    <td class="ig9a637667 ">false</td>
    <td class="ig9a637668 "></td>
    <td class="ig9a637669 ">false</td>
</tr>

<tr class=" " type="row" adr="2" tag="" id="x:442163216.17:adr:2:tag:">
    <td wlkd="1" type="cell" idx="0" adr="0" class="ig9a63765d ">45</td>
    <td class="ig9a63765e ">0</td>
    <td class="ig9a63765f ">true</td>
    <td wlkd="1" type="cell" idx="3" adr="3" class="ig9a637660 ">true</td>
    <td class="ig9a637661 ">false</td>
    <td class="ig9a637662 ">true</td>
    <td class="ig9a637663 "></td>
    <td class="ig9a637664 ">false</td>
    <td type="cell" adr="8" idx="8" class="IG_Fields_Cell IG_Cell_Selectable IG_Cell_Center ">
        <img id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Main_Main_Main_grdFields_it8_2_imgCheckVisible" src="Images/GreenCheckmarkIcon16x16.png" style="visibility:hidden;">
    </td>
    <td wlkd="1" type="cell" idx="9" adr="9" class="ig9a637665 ">false</td>
    <td tabindex="-1" wlkd="1" type="cell" adr="10" idx="10" class="IG_Fields_Cell IG_Cell_Selectable IG_Cell_Center ">
        <img id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Main_Main_Main_grdFields_it10_2_imgCheckRequired" src="Images/GreenCheckmarkIcon16x16.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
    </td>
    <td class="ig9a637666 ">Intent to Proceed Received Date</td>
    <td tabindex="-1" wlkd="1" type="cell" adr="12" idx="12" class="IG_Field_Field_Name ">Intent to Proceed Received Date</td>
    <td type="cell" adr="13" idx="13" class="IG_Fields_Cell ">Intent to Proceed Received Date</td>
    <td type="cell" adr="14" idx="14" class="IG_Fields_Cell "></td>
    <td type="cell" adr="15" idx="15" class="IG_Fields_Cell IG_Cell_Center ">
        <a href="javascript:ShowITPTracking();"><img src="/images/Configure-Icon-16x15.png" alt="" class="Configure"></a>
    </td>
    <td class="ig9a637667 ">false</td>
    <td class="ig9a637668 "></td>
    <td class="ig9a637669 ">false</td>
</tr>
```

I am getting the list of elements that have the adr=8 attribute and clicking the column if the checkmark icon is hidden like this:

```
List<WebElement> showColumn = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[class='IG_Fields_Cell IG_Cell_Selectable IG_Cell_Center'][adr='8']"));

for(WebElement show : showColumn)
{
    System.out.println("Found the element");
    // If not selected, select it
    if (show.findElement(By.tagName("img")).getAttribute("style").contains("hidden"))
    {
        show.click();
    }

}
```

However, it never enters the for loop. If I remove the [adr='8'] constraint when creating the list of elements, it enters every cell. I need only the adr=8 column...

**---UPDATE---**

It turned out that the 'idx' and 'adr' attributes do not appear until the element is hovered over. I will try using the the robot class to hover over all the elements with that class and then search for the adr attribute. Not sure how reliable that will be though.

Comment: Did you tried as `td.IG_Fields_Cell.IG_Cell_Selectable.IG_Cell_Center[adr='8']`...??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur yes, that was how I tried it initially. The above was my most recent attempt. Both ways find all elements with that class if I leave off the [adr='8']

Comment: Try once at browser console by pressing f12 using `$x("td.IG_Fields_Cell.IG_Cell_Selectable.IG_Cell_Center[adr='8']")` and see what is the result and where is the problem...

Comment: It appears that the 'idx' and 'adr' attributes do not appear until the element is hovered over, so that would be why it is not working. Maybe I could use the robot class to hover over all the elements with that class and then search? Not sure how reliable that would be though. I'll give it a shot and if it turns out to not work well, I'll just take the time to manually map out ALL the fields with their id